# can't initialize instance of class from abstract class function in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gravity-forms-plugin

I have two different plugins in wordpress. working on the compatibility issues.
Gravity forms has two abstract classes

```
abstract class A {
======
======
  function settings(){

  }
$this->Settings();
}

abstract class B extend A {
======
======
 
}
```

Now in my plugin, I have two different classes like below

```
class C extend B {

function settings(){ // override class from A
  $obj = new D();
}
}
```

and another class of my plugin is D

```
class D {
// stuff here 

}
```

the overridden function of class A in class C is being initialized from Class A. then in class C settings function I want to initialize the instance of Class D. but I am getting critical error of class not found. Any body help please.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the GF official Add Ons? There they have code examples of how to extend their classes, create your own settings, etc

Comment: https://docs.gravityforms.com/category/developers/php-api/add-on-framework/#a-simple-add-on
https://docs.gravityforms.com/gfaddon/